# extend jQuery in react app (custom chained jQuery functions)

Tags: jquery, reactjs, function, chained

BEFORE YOU FLAME ME FOR ASKING THIS, PLEASE READ: I know that react replaces 99% of the use cases for jQuery. However I want stuff to happen when the user hovers over items, and I'm not aware that react can do that. Also I have code that works in jquery and I don't want to rewrite it.

Most of my jQuery code seems to be working OK.

In my jQuery code, I have used custom chained functions. I tried pasting the code below into componentDidMount, and also directly at the bottom of index.html, but I always get:

*jQuery is not defined*.

```
jQuery.fn.extend(
{
 // returns the collection of td cells in the same column as obj_td
tableColumn: function(){
  const $td_this= ancestorTagName("td")
  // both td with right version
  var rows = this.ancestorTagName("table").find('tr');
  console.log("chain tableColumn rows=", rows)
  if (rows === $()) return $() // probably called outside a table
  // index is the number of siblings prior to this one  
  var index = $td_this.prevAll().length;  
  console.log("chain tableColumn index=", index)
  let cols = rows.find(':nth-child(' + (index + 1) + ')')
  cols=cols.filter4tag('td')
  return cols
  },
   ...
  }
```

The purpose is to use expressions like

```
let $top_Product = jqObj.tableColumn().find('.version')
```

to find a cell in the same colunmn with a **.version** class.

I do have **import $ from 'jquery';** at the top of App.js, and I did include the jquery component into the REACT project.

Comment: Thankfully, nowadays javascript has advanced enough to let us do selection/finding of elements in DOM relatively easy. Look for `document.querySelector` and `document.querySelectorAll` on MDN. If this is the only piece of logic that you consider necesary to migrate shouldn't be that hard.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, it looks interesting and I will look into that. The function I mentioned isn't the only one, however. Also it would be great if I could find a solution that would avoid re-writing stuff that works on a static page.

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/integrating-with-other-libraries.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to load jQuery globally into React first. To do this in a CRA (I am assuming you are using create-react-app) you need to adjust your Webpack config. This can be done using the npm module craco.

Once you got craco up and running you can add this to your craco.config.js to add jQuery ($) globally in React:

```
module.exports = {
    webpack: {
        plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin(
            {
                $: 'jquery',
                jQuery: 'jquery',
                'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
            },      
        ),
      ],
    }
  }
```

Be aware: All the jQuery code should be inside a useEffect hook since you are dealing with an outside system (jQuery).

Depending on your linter you'd need to add the comment `/* global $ */` in the React files that use jQuery.